# Установка SQL 2016 через Ansible

Tags: sql-server, ansible

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь поставить SQL Server 2016 на Windows Server 2012 R2 при помощи Ansible развернутом на CentOS 7.
Дистрибутив SQL лежит локально на целевой машине.
Установка запускается с помощью PS скрипта:
`"Start-Process -FilePath C:\\soft\\SQL\\en_sql_server_2016_developer_with_service_pack_2_x64_dvd_12194995\\setup.exe /configurationfile=C:\\soft\\SQL\\ConfigurationFile.ini"`

Запускаемый playbook:

```
- name: SQL Server
  hosts: testserver
  tasks:
    - name: Install MS SQL Server 2016
      win_shell: Start-Process -FilePath C:\soft\SQL\en_sql_server_2016_developer_with_service_pack_2_x64_dvd_12194995\setup.exe /configurationfile=C:\soft\SQL\ConfigurationFile.ini
```

В Ansible получаю результат:

```
changed: [172.27.46.19] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "Start-Process -FilePath C:\\soft\\SQL\\en_sql_server_2016_developer_with_service_pack_2_x64_dvd_12194995\\setup.exe /configurationfile=C:\\soft\\SQL\\ConfigurationFile.ini",
    "delta": "0:00:00.281262",
    "end": "2020-09-03 12:22:04.376021",
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2020-09-03 12:22:04.094758",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************
172.27.46.19               : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

при этом скрипт

```
C:\soft\SQL\en_sql_server_2016_developer_with_service_pack_2_x64_dvd_12194995\setup.exe /configurationfile=C:\soft\SQL\ConfigurationFile.ini
```

на целевой машине из PS запускает установку

с Ansible простой скрипт создания каталога выполняется без ошибок:

```
- name: Create a directory using PowerShell
  hosts: testserver
  tasks:
    - name: Create dir temp
      win_shell: New-Item -Path C:\Temp -ItemType Directory
```

Никто не сталкивался с подобной проблемой?
или кто подскажет где м.б. ошибка?
Спасибо!

Comment: А прям обязательно пошик дёргать?

Comment: нет, необязательно. но нужно обойтись без пакетных менеджеров типа chocalatey.

Answer (score 0):

удалось решить, путем прописывания полного конфиг файла в строку установки в качестве параметров

```
C:\soft\SQL\sql_server_2016_sp2\setup.exe `
/ACTION="Install" `
/PID="22222-00000-00000-00000-00000" `
/SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE="False" `
/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS="True" `
/IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS="False" `
/ENU="True" `
/QUIET="True" `
/QUIETSIMPLE="False" `
/UpdateEnabled="True" `
/USEMICROSOFTUPDATE="False" `
/FEATURES=SQLENGINE `
/UpdateSource="MU" `
/HELP="False" `
/INDICATEPROGRESS="False" `
/X86="False" `
/INSTANCENAME="ANSIBLE_TEST" `
/INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server" `
/INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server" `
/INSTANCEID="ANSIBLE_TEST" `
/SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" `
/SQLTELSVCACCT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" `
/INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server" `
/AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" `
/AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Manual" `
/ASBACKUPDIR `
/ASCOLLATION `
/ASCONFIGDIR `
/ASDATADIR `
/ASLOGDIR `
/COMMFABRICPORT="0" `
/COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL="0" `
/COMMFABRICENCRYPTION="0" `
/MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT="0" `
/SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" `
/FILESTREAMLEVEL="0" `
/ENABLERANU="False" `
/SQLCOLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" `
/SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" `
/SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT="False" `
/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="ANSIBLE-TEST\Administrator" `
/SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT="1" `
/SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE="8" `
/SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH="64" `
/SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE="8" `
/SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH="64" `
/ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="False" `
/TCPENABLED="0" `
/NPENABLED="0" `
/BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled"
```

можно вставить прямо в playbook в модуль win_shell:

параметры можно посмотреть тут:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Ну тогда код закинь.

Comment: Если чё - виндовый софт в 99% случаев можно ставить прям с шары.

Comment: а ссылка есть как?

Comment: На что именно? На шару? Ты сам кладёшь дистр, а в пути указываешь сетевой smb путь.

Comment: а в этом плане. это следующий этап =)